# What are the in-app purchases for Layton and the Diabolical Box on Android?

Tags: android, professor-layton-diabolical-box

The Google Play store page for [Professor Layton and the Diabolical Box on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Level5.LT2RNA) says it contains in-app purchases. I can't find any other mention of them on the store page.

What are the in-app purchases for Layton and the Diabolical Box on Android?

[image: Layton store page]

Comment: I just bought diabolical box and I haven't found any immediate, obvious references to in-app purchases. All of the weekly puzzles are available immediately from the start, and there was no blurb on the intro screen about it.

Comment: Update: Beat the game. There's nothing. How weird. I wonder if it's a Google thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There's no in-app purchases.

I've successfully:

- Completed the main game
- Finished the camera minigame
- Finished the hamster minigame
- Finished the Old Diary
- Gotten 22/26 drinkers in the Tea Set
- Completed all weekly puzzles
- Completed 137 puzzles (Didn't complete two of the Laytons Challenges set because I can't be arsed to find the last four tea drinkers)
- Unlocked every item in the "Top Secret" section.

Haven't had to pay anything.